# Terraform Launch Type Fargate for windows container Error:- You do not have authorization to access the specified platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-fargate

**Description**

**Terraform: For Launch type, Fargate with windows container getting below error after running terraform apply Error:**

error creating app-name service: error waiting for ECS service (app-name) creation: AccessDeniedException: You do not have authorization to access the specified platform.

**Below Terraform and AWS provider version used:**

Terraform CLI and Terraform AWS Provider Version
User-Agent: APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.12.31 (+https://www.terraform.io) terraform-provider-aws/3.70.0 (+https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws) aws-sdk-go/1.42.23 (go1.16; linux; amd64)

**Affected Resource(s):- aws_ecs_service**

**Terraform Configuration Files**

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app_task" {
  family                = "${var.tags["environment"]}-app"
  container_definitions = data.template_file.app_task_definition.rendered
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  task_role_arn      = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.arn
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.arn
  memory             = var.fargate_memory
  cpu                = var.fargate_cpu

  runtime_platform {
      operating_system_family = "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CORE"
      cpu_architecture = "X86_64"
    }

  depends_on = [null_resource.confd_cluster_values]
}
resource "aws_ecs_service" "app" {
  name                               = "${var.tags["environment"]}-app"
  cluster                            = data.terraform_remote_state.fargate_cluster.outputs.cluster.id
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.app_task.arn
  desired_count                      = var.ecs_app_desired_count
  health_check_grace_period_seconds  = 2147483647
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 0
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 100
  launch_type                        = "FARGATE"
  enable_execute_command             = true

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = [data.terraform_remote_state.fargate_cluster.outputs.cluster_security_group]
    subnets = data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.app.arn
    container_name   = var.alb_target_container_name
    container_port   = 8097
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [desired_count]
  }

  depends_on = [aws_ecs_task_definition.app_task]
}
```

**Debug Output**

-----------------------------------------------------: timestamp=2022-01-01T16:30:06.055+0530
2022-01-01T16:30:06.055+0530 [INFO] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.70.0_x5: 2022/01/01 16:30:06 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] **{"__type":"AccessDeniedException","message":"You do not have authorization to access the specified platform."}:** timestamp=2022-01-01T16:30:06.055+0530
2022-01-01T16:30:06.055+0530 [INFO] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.70.0_x5: 2022/01/01 16:30:06 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] **DEBUG: Validate Response ecs/CreateService failed, attempt 0/25, error AccessDeniedException: You do not have authorization to access the specified platform.**: timestamp=2022-01-01T16:30:06.055+0530

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not due to your TF code, but due to your **IAM permissions** that you use to run the code. You have to verity your permissions. You may also be limited at the AWS Organization level if your account is part of a group of accounts.

Comment: I checked permissions.
If I changed operating_system_family to LINUX I'm able to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/running-windows-containers-with-amazon-ecs-on-aws-fargate/ came to know that **Amazon ECS Exec feature is unsupported in Fargate for Windows tasks** and therefore the error occurred.

Disabling below in aws_ecs_service resolved the issue.

**enable_execute_command             = true**

It would be helpful if terraform can show users an appropriate message saying the above feature is not available for windows instead of throwing an error **"You do not have authorization to access the specified platform."**